# Creating Modal Popup using AngularJS and Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Hi I am trying to create a simple modal dialog that pops up when a user clicks a button.  I am brand new to Angular and Bootstrap and I'm having a hard time figuring it out.  I've created a plnkr here

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('crm.ma', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('AdvancedSearchCtrl', function ($modal) {
        vm.openModal = function () {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'topnav_advancedmodal.html',
                controller: 'searchCtrl as modal'
            });
        }
    })

});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VgQqRIMGewuwQPnUxm87?p=catalogue

plnkr code above.  Please help!

Comment: open plunker and look at console errors

Comment: @PetrAveryanov Do you mean to look at the console in Chrome?  I'm not very familiar with plnkr.  This is only the second time I've used it.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I see what you mean now.  I corrected the mistakes in my controller.  Now I am just getting a blank page when the application loads.

Comment: 1. I still see old plunk  2. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ -- here you can find examples and link to working plunks. 3. Always look in console for errors. 4. $modal.open simply creates several divs -- if you dont modal, then u probably forgot to include bootstrap.css

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues with your code. Here are some of them:

**JavaScript**

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('crm.ma', ['ui.bootstrap']). // You define new module with angular.module('...', []) syntax. If module is already initialised, use angular module('...') instead
    controller('searchCtrl', function() {}). // Make sure this controller exists and registered in angular
    controller('advancedSearchCtrl', ['$modal',function ($modal) { // Use ['x', function(x) {...}] syntax
        this.openModal = function () { // vm -> this
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'topnav_advancedmodal.html',
                controller: 'searchCtrl as modal' // <- make sure searchCtrl controller exists and is registered
            });
        };
    }]);

}());
```

**Plunker**

http://plnkr.co/edit/6X40tgEriHXTjBsfvkHy?p=preview